# Can't connect to MiniKF landing page on http://10.10.10.10 after installing MiniKF

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, kubeflow

I am trying to run an example machine learning pipeline on premise (meaning: locally on a Windows 10 laptop) using [MiniKF](https://www.arrikto.com/minikf/) and [Kubeflow Pipelines](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/pipelines/overview/pipelines-overview/), following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/kubeflow/an-end-to-end-ml-pipeline-on-prem-notebooks-kubeflow-pipelines-on-the-new-minikf-33b7d8e9a836), but I can't reach the site that should appear at http://10.10.10.10.

I installed:

- [Virtualbox 6.1.4](https://www.virtualbox.org/)
- [Vagrant 2.2.7](https://www.vagrantup.com/)

Then, in a CMD prompt, I ran:

```
C:\Users\jervan\Documents\minikf>vagrant init arrikto/minikf
A `Vagrantfile` has been placed in this directory. You are now
ready to `vagrant up` your first virtual environment! Please read
the comments in the Vagrantfile as well as documentation on
`vagrantup.com` for more information on using Vagrant.

C:\Users\jervan\Documents\minikf>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Using C:/Users/jervan/Documents/minikf/minikf-user-data.vdi for persistent storage.
==> default: Importing base box 'arrikto/minikf'...
==> default: Generating MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Using C:/Users/jervan/Documents/minikf/minikf-user-data.vdi for persistent storage.
==> default: Checking if box 'arrikto/minikf' version '20200305.1.0' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: minikf_default_1584993248035_85721
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 32123 (guest) => 32123 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Using C:/Users/jervan/Documents/minikf/minikf-user-data.vdi for persistent storage.
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Using C:/Users/jervan/Documents/minikf/minikf-user-data.vdi for persistent storage.
==> default: ** Creating persistent storage **
==> default: Using C:/Users/jervan/Documents/minikf/minikf-user-data.vdi for persistent storage.
==> default: ** Attaching persistent storage **
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default:
    default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    default:
    default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
    default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    default: your host and reload your VM.
    default:
    default: Guest Additions Version: 6.0.14_Ubuntu r132055
    default: VirtualBox Version: 6.1
==> default: Using C:/Users/jervan/Documents/minikf/minikf-user-data.vdi for persistent storage.
==> default: ** Managing persistent storage **
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => C:/Users/jervan/Documents/minikf

==> default: Machine 'default' has a post `vagrant up` message. This is a message
==> default: from the creator of the Vagrantfile, and not from Vagrant itself:
==> default:
==> default:     Welcome to MiniKF!
==> default:     Visit http://10.10.10.10/ to get started.
==> default:
```

But when I visit http://10.10.10.10 I get an "This site can’t be reached. 10.10.10.10 took too long to respond." error.

My Virtualbox settings look like this:

[image: Virtualbox settings]

I can ssh into the box like so:

```
C:\Users\jervan\Documents\minikf>vagrant ssh
Last login: Mon Mar 23 13:14:17 2020 from 10.0.2.2

Welcome to MiniKF!

Type "minikf" to ensure everything is up and running.

vagrant@minikf:~$
```

and when I type `minikf` I get the MiniKF Provisioing tool (which is what you [would normally see embedded in the MiniKF landing page](https://miro.medium.com/max/2400/1*5GHZGfu0CzagYG3Dv82XKQ.png)).

[image: MiniKF Provisioning tool]

After provisioning the software, I see pods starting up and the message "Kubeflow is deployed". But after the "exposing services" stage, I see errors popping up:

[image]

If I click on enter then the errors disappear, and the "Provisioning completed." screen with username and password appears.

If I go to VirtualBox and click on the green arrow, then it shows me the ubuntu login page, but I don't manage to login with the credentials shown in the previous step.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. 
First time around, it fails to start and after I run vagrant up again it starts, but I cannot access 10.10.10.10
[errors I had](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8F3A.png)

Then I went into the vm itself and shut it down like this :

[shutting down the VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmsqe.png)

After shutting it down manually, I did vagrant up again and now I can access 10.10.10.10